# Question related to binomial distribution

Tags: distributions, probability, binomial-distribution, function

Let $X \sim Binomial (n, p)$ with both $n$ and $p$ known.
Suppose for some non-increasing function $G:[0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$, 
and some fixed $c_0 \in [0,1]$,
we have that 
\begin{align} \label{ineq}
P(G(X/n) \leq c_0) \leq \alpha    
\end{align}
where $\alpha$ can be chosen as 0.1.  Let $\mathcal{G}$ be 
set that contains all the functions satisfy the above inequality.
I want to find the smallest such function $G_0$ such that 
$G_0 \in \mathcal{G}$ and $G_0(x) \leq G(x), \quad \forall x \in [0,1]$, where
$G$ is any other function in $\mathcal{G}$. Can anyone give some hint on looking for such a function.

Comment: It seems this is a discrete problem, because it involves only the values of $G$ at $0, 1/n, 2/n, \ldots, 1$: that might help you work through some instructive examples as well as help you reformulate the question in a simpler manner. Note that in general a smallest such function does not exist.

Comment: I am curious about what is the underlying motivation for the question.  It looks very abstract but i have a hunch that you have some specific application in  mind.

Comment: I agree $G_0$ might not exist in general. I was wondering whether in this particular case the problem is solvable. Thanks for your comment Whuber.

Comment: Is $c_0$ the same for all functions in the $\mathscr{G}$-class?

Comment: $c_0$ is the fixed for all functions in $\mathcal{G}$. This question is not related to any statistical tests. The background will not be easily explained and I thought it is not really relevant. I just want to see whether it is feasible to find a function $G_0$ with given conditions. Thank you very much.